# Combination of bayesian models in pymc3

Tags: regression, bayesian, multivariate-analysis, pymc

Simplified problem is: I noted down peoples’ physiological parameters (age, BMI, resting heart rate, etc.) and asked them to perform exercises. From that I measured their HRmax and how well they perform (speed) and how long it takes to recover (recoveryTime).
I have 3 linear models also related to each other like this (it is my assumption based on expert knowledge):

HRmax ~ Age + BMI + HRrest
Speed ~ Age + HRmax
RecoveryTime ~ HRrest + HRmax + Speed

I have N people-records with full information about all predictors and responses, but in the end I am interested to predict how well people will do the exercise (Speed), but also RecoveryTime and HRmax are of secondary interest, because I want to tell all three without asking someone to do the exercise, but just from their physiology metrics.

How do I design such a model and implement it in pymc3?
Do I make three models and them combine them somehow?
Or is this one model with three likelihoods?

I appreciate if you can help me with an explanation, references or indicating silly assumptions I have about Bayesian modeling.

Comment: Your aims aren't clear: could you explain what you mean by "such a model," given you have presented *three* models?

Comment: @whuber thanks, I explained it in more details. yes, I have three models describing one problem, but responses of two models are inputs (predictors) in the third model.

Comment: Thank you--that clears up many things.  But could you explain the sense in which any of these models are "Bayesian"?  What parameters are you modeling with prior distributions?